# login form needs to be completed a number of times before it logs in

Tags: php, html, forms, authentication

I have a login form (HTML -> PHP). I enter the correct details, it then reloads the page and i have to enter the details again. I press submit and then it does it again. On the third time (sometimes the second I think) it actually logs me in.

**Any help would be greatly appreciated.**

Here is the forms HTML:

```
<!-- Login Form -->
                    <form method="post" id="login-form-splash">
                    <input type="text" class="text" name="username" onfocus="if(this.value == 'Username') { this.value = ''; }" value="Username" />
                    <input type="password" name="password" class="password" onfocus="if(this.value == 'Password') { this.value = ''; }" value="Password" />
                    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login" class="submit" />
                    <br />
                    <a href="resetpassword.php"><span>Lost Password?</span></a>
                    <br />
                    No account yet? <a href="register.php">Register</a>.<br />
            </form>
```

And here is the PHP actually doing the login:

```
<?php
//Check if login form was submitted.
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{   

    //include important settings and functions.
    include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/includes/config.php');

    //Check if both fields were completed.
    if($_POST['username'] == '' || $_POST['password'] == '')
    {
        //Tell them whats wrong.
        echo "<script language=\"javascript\">alert('You need to complete both fields.');</script>";
    }   else
        {
            //The completed both fields.
            //Localise vars.
            $username = $_POST['username'];
            $password = $_POST['password'];

            //Protect against SQL Injection using mysql_prep function. [mysql_prep can be found in ./includes/functions.php]
            mysql_prep($username);
            mysql_prep($password);

            //MD5 Hash the password to check against hashed password in DB.
            $password = md5($password);

            //Connect to MySQL Database.
            include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/includes/connect.php');

            //If connection exists
            if(isset($mysql_connection))
            {
                //Run MySQL Query on DB.
                $sql = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `username` = '$username' AND `password` = '$password'";
                $result = mysql_query($sql, $mysql_connection) or die('Cannot Execute:'. mysql_error());

                //Check if there is a match. There can only be one.
                if(mysql_num_rows($result) == 1)
                {
                    //Create session variables and set values within them.
                    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;

                    //Redirect to Members page.
                    header('Location: members.php'); 
                }   else
                    {
                        //Username and Password are not correct, or the account doesn't exist.
                        echo "<script language=\"javascript\">alert('Please check that you have entered the details correctly.');</script>";
                    }
            }   else
                {
                    //Database error.
                    echo "<script language=\"javascript\">alert('There was a database error. Please try again or contact a technician at errors@eatgamesleep.com');</script>";
                }
        }
}
?>
```

Comment: Does mysql_prep return anything/what does it do? You might want to add a `exit;` after your header.

Comment: Maybe you are checking if the user is logged in before actually logging him in? For example: "Check if the user is logged in -> set variable $userIsLoggedIn = false -> handle form requests -> parse page". The mistake would require a second page load to actually recognize the user as logged in.

Comment: Another thing: Do the sessions work correctly? Try using session_start() at the beginning of every page file.

Comment: DiViSOR, thanks for your reply. This could definitely be the issue. I'm quite new to PHP, would you have any ideas on how I could fix it? Yeah my sessions work, im using sessions successfully in the rest of the project.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should replace

```
 if(isset($mysql_connection)) {
```

to just

```
if($mysql_connection){
```